# Google Sheets Formula: List item from Column A if Column B is < or > a given value

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working on listing out a long list of "battle items" for a game. I need to categorize them into their Tiers (Tier 1 are battle items of a worth less than 1000 t, for example). I'd like for Google Sheets to do this automatically, rather than go through the list by hand.

[Google Sheet Image Cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IieMZ.jpg)

End result would be:

1. Sheets checks based on criteria (< 1000, > 1000 but < 50,000, or
   50,000+).
2. Sorts the list of items (col a) under the tiers as
   appropriate. (Tier 1 = > 1000, Tier 2 < 1000, Tier 3 50,000+)
3. The *Name of the Item* is listed under the correct Tier.

I'm not looking for a total, I'm not looking to count how many, I just need it sorted.

[Example of what I want it to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3btw.jpg)

I would count myself a Beginner (just under the intermediate) level of Google Sheets User - I know enough to do some things, but not enough to do really advanced arrays and the like. This is where my knowledge breaks down, as I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do can be done.

I have searched with Google, looked through the Sheets help files and questions posed by others, and haven't found what I needed. I have tried Query, but my formatting may be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper column named Tier in Column C:

```
C2 =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B6>50000,3,IF(B2:B6>1000,2,1)))
```

Now create a new table:

E1:

```
  =TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(C2:C6))
```

E2:

```
  =FILTER($A$2:$A$6,$C$2:$C$6=E$1)
```

Drag fill to the right.